# Login Page, how to check 3 tables for ID & Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i'm creating a `login` page for my web application in `ASP.net` & `C#`, using visual studio 2010.

My `login` page is empty, just has 2 `text boxes` for `username` and `password` and a `submit button`, with some required field `validations` on each control.

I'm using `SQL Server 2012` and have 3 tables in there, **`Student`**, **`Staff`**, and **`Admins`**, each one has two columns for `Username` and `password`.

What i would like to do is when the user presses the `submit` button, it checks the student table for the `username` and its `password`, if its not there, it checks the `staff`, then the `admins`. If its not in any of them, it gives an `error` that the login failed.

I put an `SQLdatasource` on the page that pulls the `username` and `password` from the `student` table where they are equal to the `textboxes` text.

Do i need to add 3 `sqldatasources` to page for each `table`? and what do i have to do after that?

Comment: Honestly, you should refactor the DB and have a users table that has the username and HASHED password for all users, with a foreign key relationship to the student, staff, and admins tables (if there is data specific to them) or simply a type identifier in the users table as to their role.  And if you are storing unhashed passwords, shame shame.

Comment: DB planning,you really need to redo it ! single table,a field called userTypeId will do,Student=1, Staff=2, and Admins=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - I agree that you should perhaps refactor, but to answer your question:

Since you are only reading data you can use a union over your three tables in your select.

Example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

```
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM Production.ProductModel
WHERE ProductModelID NOT IN (3, 4)
UNION
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM dbo.Gloves
ORDER BY Name;
GO
```

and modify the `SelectCommand` in your datasource.

Comment: thank you very much, that worked. But now to go on with the login process, after my datasource compares with the data in the union, what code goes into my button?

Comment: I have the impression you are reinventing the wheel. You should have a look at the Membership system in asp.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You will need to do something to your tables in order to work with the standard membership system but it might save you a lot of work in the long rung. Have you considered it?